# Is it possible to change the geolocation settings or completely disable geolocation for smartphone with developer mode?

Tags: geolocation, operating-system

Can I change the geolocation settings with developer mode? For example make the main positioning mode with using only WI fi network  instead of using  GPS +GSM +WI fi?

Or it can be done only with root?

Comment: See Android settings "...Location" -> Location. There you can disable locations for all apps. I am not sure if "all" in this case also includes system apps.